# Adding arrays and objects in javascript produces an error

Tags: javascript, object

I get these outputs when the following operations are carried out

```
var t = {} + {}; // Alerts [object Object][object Object]
t = {} + 1 //Alerts [object Object]1
t = {} + "hello" //Alerts [object Object]hello
t = {} + function(){} //Alerts [object Object]function(){}
t = {} + [] //Alerts [object Object]
```

In the last case alone it alerts `[Object object]` shouldn't it display `[object Object][object Object]` for this too?

Tested in Firefox12.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because the second part of the output is the stringified form of the empty array `[]`. Arrays are stringified as a comma-separated list of stringified values, so the empty array stringifies to the empty string. You can confirm this with `console.log([] + "" === "")`.

Therefore, `{} + []` results in the equivalent `"[object Object]" + ""`.

Comment: Just to add that when evaluating the [addition operator +](http://es5.github.com/#x11.6.1), each expression is converted to a primitive by calling its `toString` method (if it has one).